# Set is differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the largest set on which the function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \textrm{ if } x\neq 0\\
\\
0 & \textrm{ if } x=0
\end{cases}
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R$ is differentiable. Justify your answer.

I thought it would be all real numbers because it is defined for all real numbers. But I was confused to whether it is differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Hint: What happens if you try to work out $\lim_{h\to0}(f(h)-f(0))/h$?

Comment: wouldnt there be a 0 in the denominator so it doesnt exist?

Comment: What? If you're _proving_ things about differentiablility you need to start by learning the _defininition_ of the derivative.

Comment: Yeah my understanding of the definition is very confused.

Answer (score 0):

To check differentiability at $x=0$, you need to consider the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{(0+h)-0}.$$ Simplifying, we see that $$\frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{(0+h)-0} = \frac{h\sin\left( \tfrac 1 h \right)}{h} = \sin\left( \tfrac 1 h \right).$$ So you need to either show that $$\lim_{h\to 0} \sin\left( \tfrac 1 h \right) $$ exists or does not exist.

Comment: isnt it obvious it wouldnt because you cant have 0 in the denominator?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is obvious for that reason. What about $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}?$$ This limit will also have $0$ in a denominator, but this limit exists.

Comment: isnt that becuase of La'hopitals rule?

Comment: Sure. I'm just trying to demonstrate that "it has zero in the denominator, therefore the limit doesn't exist" is potentially faulty reasoning.